# Bending moment as product of thickness and deflection?

Tags: structural-beam

I'm reading [a book on shape optimization](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898718690) and in p.3. the author gives an example of optimizing the thickness of a vertical beam represented by the interval $I=[0,1]$ (so it's a line) and under a uniform vertial load $f_0$. The thickness is denoted by $e$ and the deflection $u:= u(e)$ of the beam solves the following 4th order BVP:

\begin{cases}
(\beta e^3u''(x))''=f_0,  & \text{in [0,1]} \\
u(0)=u(1)=(\beta e^3u'')(0)=(\beta e^3 u'')(1)=0
\end{cases}

The author then provides a weak formulation of the above, a Lagrangian and optimality conditions. Later he moves onto defining the bending moment as $$M:=M(x)=(e^3 u'')(x)$$

What I don't understand is, how can this be the bending moment? Thickness cubed times the second derivative of deflection? Does this make any sense? Perhaps I've missed something in the text?

Answer (score 2):

The abstract of the OP's book says

> By presenting sizing and shape optimization in an abstract way ...

which may be code-words for "we made up our own notation".

The equation seems to be a version of the relationship between bending moment and curvature for a beam $$M = \frac{EI}{\rho}.$$

If the slope of small, the radius of curvature $\rho$ is related to the second derivative of displacement $u$ by $$\frac{1}{\rho} = \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$$ and $I$ is presumably proportional to $e^3$.

Mathematicians like working in units where as many constants as possible are equal to $1$, so their equations look simpler - they can delegate worrying about the properties of real-world materials to inferior life forms such as engineers (/irony).

Answer (score 2):

For small deflexions, $u^{\prime\prime}$ is a good approximation of the beam's curvature $\kappa(x)$. Then, if we think of the beam as being made up of fibers, and if $y$ the co-ordinate measuring the transverse position in the plane of curvature, the strain in a fiber a distance $y$ from the neutral axis is $\kappa\,y$. The stress is then $E\,\kappa\,y$ with $E$ the Young's modulus and so bending moment is $E\,\int_{-\frac{e}{2}}^{\frac{e}{2}}\,\kappa\,y^2\,\mathrm{d}\,y$.

So the bending moment is $\frac{E\,e^3}{12}\,u^{\prime\prime}$. From here, I'm guessing that the author is choosing normalized units so that $E=12$.